# Crash when closing PDF in uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Im opening a PDF from the button hulp

This is the code:

```
-(IBAction)hulp;
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Handleiding" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
webView.tag=55;
[[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,500) animated:YES];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, 50.0)"]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80, 425, 160, 40);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[webView addSubview:button];

}


- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {

[[self.view viewWithTag:55] removeFromSuperview];


}
```

Does anyone see what im doing wrong:

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LocationTestViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8087c60'
  *** First throw call stack:
 (0x1f26012 0x15e8e7e 0x1fb14bd 0x1f15bbc 0x1f1594e 0x15fc705 0x38c920 0x38c8b8 0x44d671 0x44dbcf 0x44c872 0x3bc16d 0x3bc552 0x39a3aa 0x38bcf8 0x22badf9 0x22baad0 0x1e9bbf5 0x1e9b962 0x1eccbb6 0x1ecbf44 0x1ecbe1b 0x22b97e3 0x22b9668 0x38965c 0x244d 0x2385)
  libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
 (lldb)
```

Comment: How have you implemented aMethod: in your class? Post the code please.

Comment: i onl added in my.h file - (IBAction)close:(id)sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this instruction for:

```
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Remove it.